# How can I specify nameserver's port number in osx?

Tags: mac-osx, nameserver, domain-name-system

In resolver [manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/resolver.5.html), it said:

The address may optionally have a trailing dot followed by a port number.
 For example, **10.0.0.17.55** specifies that
the nameserver at **10.0.0.17**
 uses port **55**.

But it doesn't work, in /etc/resolv.conf or files under /etc/resolver/.

**208.67.222.222.5353**

Can I specify non-default port number for nameserver in osx?

Update:

osx don't use /etc/resolve.conf, but use files under /etc/resolver/. I have wrote a file `dev` with content '127.0.0.1' to route all dns queries for *.dev domains to a local dns server (127.0.0.). But I cannot specify dns server's port here. (It uses 53 anyway)

Maybe there is no way to specify port number under osx?

Comment: Sounds like OSX doesn't user /etc/resolve.conf, start looking elsewhere.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because the "duplicate" question doesn't answer this one. This is specifically about setting the DNS ***port*** and not  just the IP.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please re-open. The linked to answer has nothing to do with specifying a port other than 53 for a nameserver which is clearly documented in the man page https://www.unix.com/man-page/opendarwin/5/resolver/ which the user clearly provided.

Answer (score 0):

OSX doesn't use /etc/resolv.conf -- the information in that file is generated for your information only: it's meant to be read, not written.

See this answer here for how to modify your resolver configuration under OSX:

- [How is DNS lookup configured for OSX Mountain Lion?](https://serverfault.com/a/478540/6800)